# How can I get pandas read_csv converters to set the type on parsing?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a CSV like:

```
foo,geo,bar
1,{"country": "SG"},{}
2,{"country": "US"},{"id": "1234"}
```

I want to parse the JSON into a specific type, not just `object`. My type:

```py
geo_type = pd.ArrowDtype(pyarrow.struct([
    ('country', pyarrow.dictionary(pyarrow.uint8(), pyarrow.utf8()))
]))
```

This doesn't work:

```py
pd.read_csv(data,
            converters={'geo': lambda v: pd.Series([json.loads(v)], dtype=geo_type)})
```

This does:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(data, converters={'geo': json.loads})
df['geo'] = df['geo'].astype(geo_type)
```

What am I missing? Loading everything as python dicts and then converting them is really heavy on memory compared to parsing things into the correct types from thestart.

Comment: Can you confirm that each single line in your csv represents a JSON object? Can you add a few more lines to the shown csv (to reflect the actual structure) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It does not, otherwise I could've used a nl-json reader, there's multiple columns where some have specific JSON structures in them. That specific column is always is always a JSON string like `{"country": <2-letter-iso-country-code>}`, but while others have optional keys set like `{a}`, `{b}`, `{a,b}`, `{}`. The value for a key is always following the same schema. That said I'm specifically asking how I can handle loading a column from CSV into a specific type during parsing, rather than loading the entire column into memory as python dicts, only to convert it after.

Comment: So, Can you add a few more lines to the shown csv (to reflect the actual structure) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've added 2 more columns and another row to make it more mixed.

Comment: "I'm specifically asking how I can handle loading a column from CSV into a specific type during parsing" - you can restrict parsing to that specific column with `usecols=['geo']` so that your initial attempt would work

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Ah I see what you're confused about, I'm not asking how to *only* parse out a single column. I'm asking how to parse out a specific column that's a JSON string into the correct data type that is a struct without having to type cast it after it's already in memory. Calling `df.astype` works, but that means it's all in memory which is significantly larger, but I want to happen in the converter.